# Freemarker Not Letting Me Set Font

Tags: primefaces, freemarker, primefaces-extensions

A couple of months ago this application I wrote stopped rendering pdf correctly.
Everything used to work great with primefaces extensions pe:documentViewer.

I dont know what changed but now if I try and set the font, nothing renders in the popup.
If I remove the **font-family:Courier, monospace;** it renders...

This is my FTL template

```
<#ftl output_format="XML" auto_esc=true>
<#include '/base_macros.ftl'>
<div style="font-family:Courier, monospace; font-size: 14px;">
    
    <#-- <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>${header!}</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>-->
    <table>
        <#list portDataList as portData>
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space: pre-wrap;">${portData.data!}</td>
            </tr>
        </#list>
    </table>
</div>
```

[F12'd Popup Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCW25.png)

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't interpret CSS or HTML, only the browser does. Check what you have in the source view (F12 in the browser) of that popup.

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces (Extensions) related?

Comment: @ddekany Attached is the inspected html from the pe:documentViewer's popup. I've noticed all these extra div tags and something is making the color transparent. If I uncheck that, I can see all of my data. Did something change a couple a months ago? I had to attach a picture to the original post...

Comment: @ddekany, so I sysout'd after the freemarker transform and it's perfect html. Looking deeper into this I believe the problem is when we use flying saucer to transform the html string into a pdf stream. There have been no code changes just updates to chrome as they do. Flying saucer is defaulting to pdf 1.4, do the new versions of browsers not support that?

Comment: @Jasper de Vries because everything was working smoothly with pe:documentviewer and then all of the sudden stopped...